# Очень "простая" на первый взгляд проблема с TextView

Tags: android, activity, android-layout, glsurfaceview

Делаю игру на андроид с использованием спрайтов. В качестве главного ContentView использую класс унаследованный от SurfaceView. Ну и что бы добавлять на такой ContentView виджеты создаю Linearlayout, в нем содержатся кнопка и TextView и леплю его(layout) выше с помощью addContentView. Вроде ничего сложного. Так вот, мистика в том, что мне нужно менять текст в TextView время от времени, для этого я создал отдельную функцию, и она хоть и меняет текст в TextView, но этого не видно, пока не нажмешь на кнопку. То есть я изменил текст в textView - изменений нет. Нажал на кнопку - изменения появились. Я не знаю как это работает, хотя нажатие на кнопку ничего не выполняет. Вот сам код главной Activity где все происходит:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView tx1;
Button bL;
LinearLayout mainLayout;  //открытые переменные для использования в функциях
GameView gv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    MainActivity m = this;
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    gv = new GameView(this, m);
    setContentView(gv);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();///РАЗМЕР
    display.getSize(size);

    mainLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this); //ОСНОВНОЙ СЛОЙ
    addContentView(mainLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    bL = new Button(this);
    bL.setText("upgrades");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linnear_lay = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size.x / 3, size.y / 14); // высота и ширина
    linnear_lay.topMargin = size.y - size.y / 11;
    linnear_lay.leftMargin = size.x - size.x / 3;
    bL.setLayoutParams(linnear_lay);
    ///////КНОПКА


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams main_lay = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size.x / 2, size.y / 8); // высота и ширина
    tx1 = new TextView(this);
    tx1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    main_lay.topMargin = size.y - size.y / 4 + size.y / 12;
    main_lay.leftMargin = (-size.x / 2) - size.x / 2;
    tx1.setLayoutParams(main_lay);
    //TEXTVIEW

    //ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ ЭЛЕМЕНТОВ
    mainLayout.addView(bL);
    mainLayout.addView(tx1);


    bL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Нажал на кнопку? Молодец. Ничего не произошло
        }
    });


}


public void changeStats(int damage, int speed, int rate, long money) {

    String s = "Damage: " + damage + "\nSpeed: " + speed + "\nRate of fire: " + rate + "ms\nMoney: " + money + "$";//функция для быстрого изменения TextView
    tx1.setText(s);
}

}
```

Как я не пытаюсь эмитировать нажатие кнопки(каждый раз когда мне нужно обновить textView) ничего не выходит.

1. Я вызывал у кнопки (bL) метод CallOnClick - ноль реакции.
2. Я вызвал у mainLayout методы invalidate() и forceLayout() (из-за метода requestLayout приложение вылетает). Тоже самое с textView'ом - ноль реакции
3. Я пытался решить проблему удалнием и добавлением одного и того же виджета каждый раз, когда мне нужно обновить TV - приложение вылетает
4. Ну и когда я совсем отчаялся я почему то решил что будет адекватно каждый раз когда требуется по новой вызывать setContentView и за ним addContentView - приложение вылетело.

Мучаюсь с проблемой уже часа 3, да и поисковик особо не поможет в такой ситуации, все таки это достаточно узконаправленная проблема, и сложно найти что то похожее. Кто нибудь может подсказать что еще можно сделать?

Comment: Скорее всего дело в `addContentView()` методе. Ни разу за годы практики его не встречал. Что именно вы хотите с его помощью сделать? Возможно вам надо не в активити вашу вью добавлять, но в SurfaceView или в к-л другой контейнер стандартными средствами? Т.е. что-то типа `someGroupView.addView(mainLayout)`?

Comment: А Вы, собственно, текст меняете в основном потоке?

Comment: Создайте FrameLayout с вашим GameView и mainLayout над ним. А то как-то необычно вы тут все делаете...